# No Wireless with Dell Inspiron 1501

Tags: wireless, upgrade

I have a Dell Inspiron 1501 laptop and I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04. However, now my wireless card doesn't work whereas it worked just fine in 10.10 and 10.04. Any ideas? It works fine when I hardwire.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 9):

This link just got my wireless working on a inspiron 1501

http://blog.tech4him.com/2011/09/broadcom-wireless-on-ubuntu-11-04-and-11-10/

Thanks to the author

He uses two commands

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

dunno what that does exactly I am also a newbie but I would rather be lucky than good !

Comment: I can confirm that just installing firmware-b43-installer alone does the trick on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 as well!

Comment: The above worked for me on Peppermint 4.0. I rebooted after and presto, wireless working.

Answer (score 1):

open synaptic package manager, and install b43, do NOT install the driver from the Additional drivers. You'll need to start the wireless with Fn+F2 each boot, still looking for a solution for that issue. But that is the way I make my broadcom bcm4311 working in my Dell Inspiron 1501.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem some users are having with the new version 12.04 telling them it is a proprietary driver and it will refuse to load it. However, I have worked around this.  Use the cutter above if you feel it will work, however if it doesn't just copy all of the files for your card into a brand new directory I'll put the commands below.

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43 
sudo cp /Directory_Where_Drivers_Are /lib/firmware/b43 
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

In your text editor add the line b43 at the bottom, then save the file.
Reboot your system and it will recognize your card and forget the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

THEN UNPLUG ETHERNET AND REBOOT

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you may need a non free wireless card driver. You may try the following: Connect to your ethernet , start the 'Additional drivers' program and search to find if it detects and non free drivers your wireless card.
From the commnad line its

```
/usr/bin/jockey-gtk
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Inspiron E1505 wireless card. What worked for me was I removed the driver using the Additional Drivers program and then installed the firmware-b43-installer package. Upon reboot the card worked beautifully

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, was using these commands:

```
sudo modprobe -rv dell-laptop
sudo modprobe -v b43
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to add more detail about what those commands do, to convince the original poster of the quality of your answer.