# Can't get wireless to work on a Dell Inspiron 1501

Tags: 11.10, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No Wireless with Dell Inspiron 1501](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36905/no-wireless-with-dell-inspiron-1501)

I'm new to the world of linux-based os.  I over-writed windows xp with 11.04 on a dell inspiron 1501.  Wireless picked itself up and everything worked great.  When updates to the os presented themselves, I always clicked yes and it all worked; I assumed that a new distro would naturally work but when I dl'ed it 'was missing some firmware' (I didn't make note of what firmware it was missing).  I have scoured the forums for a solution and nothing has worked. In dummy language, please tell me what to do so that my wireless-capable laptop can go wireless again.

I've tried to reinstall 11.04 all over and it still won't pick up the signal; I've tried to install the latest distro of Kubuntu and it didn't work.  At this point I have 11.10 installed and can only use it through a wired connection.