# How do I cleanly remove NDISwrapper?

Tags: wireless, drivers, ndiswrapper

A while back (and for some time) I used [this forum post at UbuntuForums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1741197&postcount=1) to get the Broadcom wireless on my Dell Inspiron 1521 working properly.  Now, a [better method has been made available here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36905/no-wireless-with-dell-inspiron-1501) and I want to clean out the junk left by my attempt at using the old NDISwrapper method.

I'm thinking i need to remove the last line of `/etc/modules` and `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` ... There's probably more though, like `sudo make uninstall` (ndiswrapper).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this website [Unstall NDISwrapper](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Uninstall_HowTo). The main thing to make sure is the ndiswrapper module is not loading at boot and the /etc/ndiswrapper directory if clean or removed.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll be trying it out ASAP, as it's not my main computer, I'm not on it very often.

Comment: I hate to say it but the link is broken which is why they always recommend including the highlights of the link in your answer.